# Sorting a list of dictionaries by a specific dictionary key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries:

```
LeaderBoard = [{'Driver':'Sebastian Williams', 'Car':1, 'Team':'Red Drink','Grid':2, 'Fastest Lap':'1:37.481','Race Time':'2:27:45.958','Points':10},
                   {'Driver':'Tom Hamilton' ,'Car':44 ,'Team':'Mercidas' ,'Grid':6 ,'Fastest Lap':'1:37.176' ,'Race Time':'2:26:52.094' ,'Points':25 },
                   {'Driver':'Danny Ricardo' ,'Car':3 ,'Team':'Red Drink' ,'Grid':8 ,'Fastest Lap':'1:38.459' ,'Race Time':'2:27:38.589' ,'Points':15 },
                   {'Driver':'Walter Borras' ,'Car':77 ,'Team':'Lewis' ,'Grid':14 ,'Fastest Lap':'1:38.264' ,'Race Time':'2:27:22.229' ,'Points':18 },
                   {'Driver':'Fernando Sonal' ,'Car':14 ,'Team':'Farrori' ,'Grid':16 ,'Fastest Lap':'1:38.587' ,'Race Time':'2:27:52.040' ,'Points':8 },
                   {'Driver':'Jeson Smith' ,'Car':22 ,'Team':'McMilan' ,'Grid':3 ,'Fastest Lap':'1:38.284' ,'Race Time':'2:27:39.484' ,'Points':12},]
```

How do I sort them in order of quickest 'Race Time'?

I have tried everything I can think of. I used `replace` and `split` to make the race times individual numbers that I could compare easily, but I couldn't get the loops working.

This is for homework, where we need to use a sorting algorithm we have learned.  Using Python's `sort` or `sorted` is not allowed.

No other restrictions --- any way of sorting that array of dictionaries will be fine.

Comment: Use `array[0]['d'] > array[1]['d']`

Comment: Hi, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about asking questions in SO.

Comment: What do you want your output to be?  Dictionaries are not ordered data structures, so sorting their contents makes no sense.  Maybe a list for each unique key? Something else?

Comment: Please [edit] your question include _all_ restrictions your teacher has placed on this assignment.  Playing "guess the spec" in comments is no fun for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` with the `key` argument.

```
array = sorted(array,key= lambda x: x['d'])
```

Comment: Not allowed it's for a school work where we need to use a sorting algorithm we have learnt.

Comment: Ok, in that case I guess you have to work it out yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to use your own sorting code, most answers on this site won't help you --- they're generally based on the `sort` or `sorted` functions that come with Python.

You can sort these dictionaries using a slight variant of whatever sorting function you already have.  Wherever your old code compares two items like:

```
if a < b:
    # swap a and b
```

...you'll instead compare values contained in those items:

```
attribute = 'Race Time'
if a[attribute] < b[attribute]:
    # swap a and b
```

Note that your "race times" are actually strings in some weird format that will require work to convert into comparable numbers.  This will probably be worth writing as a separate function, which your sorting function would use in exactly the same places:

```
if race_time(a) < race_time(b):
    ...
```

...or even:

```
if is_faster(a, b):
    ...
```

For a more general solution, look up **comparator functions**, which most languages use for general-purpose sorting, and **key functions**, a more efficient variant used in modern versions of Python.  ("[How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python)", mentioned by SuperBiasedMan in the comments, has many examples of using key functions.)